# Add labels to the top of a tkinter grid?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

The point of this is to press a button and have new rows appear but currently, titles appear above each new row that is added. Instead, I would like to have one row at the top of the grid with column titles. Is there a way to modify this code I already have? Later, I will be incorporating this into a larger tkinter GUI.

```
from tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

def addbox():
    frame =Frame(root)
    frame.pack()

    #Item  
    Label(frame, text="Item").grid(row=0, column=0)

    ent1 = Entry(frame, width=10)
    ent1.grid(row=2, column=0)

    #Day
    Label(frame, text="Day").grid(row=0, column=1)
    ent2 = Entry(frame, width=10)
    ent2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    #Code
    ent3 = Entry(frame, width=10)
    ent3.grid(row=2, column=2)

    #Factor
    ent4 = Entry(frame, width=10)
    ent4.grid(row=2, column=3)

    all_entries.append( (ent1, ent2, ent3, ent4) )


    #Buttons. 
    showButton = Button(frame, text='Print', command=refresh)
    addboxButton = Button(frame, text='Add Item', fg="Red", command=addbox)



#------------------------------------

def refresh():

    for number, (ent1, ent2, ent3, ent4) in enumerate(all_entries):
        print (number, ent1.get(), ent2.get(), ent3.get(),ent4.get())

#------------------------------------

all_entries = []

root = Tk()

addboxButton = Button(root, text='Add Instrument', fg="Red", command=addbox)
addboxButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the row count before you add the label:

```
if len(all_entries) < 1: 
    Label(frame, text="Item").grid(row=0, column=0)
```